# How to make background image expand proportionally in IE 8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a div with a background image, within a wrapping as such:

```
<div id="imageholder">
  <div id="image">
  </div>
</div>

#imageholder {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#image {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url(image.jpg);
background-size: cover;
/*IE HACK*/
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.jpg', sizingMethod='scale'); 
}
```

The filter IE method works somewhat - it stretches the image length wise but not proportionally height wise, like background-size:cover does.

Does anyone know a way to stretch the background image proportionally in IE (so the vertical overflow is hidden by #imageholder)?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, no method to scale the image in proportion except increase size of the image holder. Here you can set height of imageHolder to percent proportionate to the image referred in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put imageholder height auto or in percentage.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want the image to cover the screen just to cover the 500px x 100% div box so that if it exceeds 500px in height it will be cropped

Answer (score 0):

I made a way to do this in JQuery. Its not the proper way and I dont like it but it may help someone:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

var windowwidth = $(window).width();

var windowsize = windowwidth - 500;

var windowsize = windowsize + "px";

if(windowwidth > 1100){

      $('#image').css({ height: windowsize });

};

});
```